# HP laptop Kubuntu/Win8 dual boot loader not working

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, lubuntu, windows-8, hp

I'm very new to Linux and this has been my first real experience with it aside from comp-sci classes. I've installed Lubuntu 14.04 alongside the stock Windows 8. To start, my laptop is an HP 2000 with dual core AMD E300 and 4Gb ram, `UEFI`. When i first tried to install Lubuntu, I could only get to grub through `Esc-F9-Ubuntu`. I played with the boot file to try and get it to work, as suggested in the below links

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

[How do I get my HP laptop to boot into grub from my new efi file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244261/how-do-i-get-my-hp-laptop-to-boot-into-grub-from-my-new-efi-file)

However, when i went into BIOS and turned off the `"secure boot"` option, it booted into GRUB right away.  The trouble is that when i selected the windows option, it took me right back to grub again.  So I turned the secure back on and was able to restore windows and get back in.  How do I fix this?  Thank you!

> `EDIT:`Boot Repair gave me this:

"An error occurred during the repair.

Please write on a paper the following URL:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7779731/"