# Dual boot problem win8.1/ubuntu14.4

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows

I need to know how to get to Ubuntu directly without opening Windows 8.1 Then i have to go to Metro screen and press Power icon and holding Shift key and clicking on Restart Choose,
I want to know how to get to page that make me choose between Operating Systems

Comment: Follow the instructions in http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Comment: Sounds like Windows is UEFI and Ubuntu is BIOS boot mode? You need to have Ubuntu installed in UEFI boot mode. Boot-Repair can convert if it is not in UEFI mode. Also many vendors now modify UEFI to only boot the Windows entry and need work arounds to boot Ubuntu. Most popular seems to be the rename of bootx64.efi to really be a grub or shim file. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 Not just HP: http://askubuntu.com/questions/244261/how-do-i-get-my-hp-laptop-to-boot-into-grub-from-my-new-efi-file

Answer (score 0):

- Restart the computer.
- Press the F2 key to enter computer's BIOS Setup during Power-On Self-Test, or POST, process while the Acer logo is being displayed.
- Press the Right Arrow key to select Main.
- Select F12 Boot Menu.
- Press the Enter key.
- Select Enabled.
- Press the Enter key.

[source](https://acer.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3182/~/why-cant-i-get-the-f12-boot-menu-to-work-on-my-notebook-or-netbook%3F)