# GRUB not appearing after installing Ubuntu 15.04 on Windows 10 dual-boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, uefi, secure-boot

I have recently upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10. I tried to install Ubuntu 15.04 in dual boot configuration.

PROBLEM: The system directly boots into Windows without the GRUB screen appearing.

Here is what I have tried till now:

1. Running boot repair. I disabled Secure Boot before running boot repair from Ubuntu image on USB stick.
2. I tried to boot into Windows and then type the following command in the admin command prompt: 
   `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`

URL to boot repair log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12256815/

Please suggest some alternative method.

Comment: Most with HP have to copy grub or shim to bootx64.efi and boot hard drive entry. https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair AND:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/244261/how-do-i-get-my-hp-laptop-to-boot-into-grub-from-my-new-efi-file