# I installed Ubuntu and only Windows boots

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

I installed the most recent version of Ubuntu (as of 9/10/15) and my PC only boots to Windows 8.  I am somewhat computer illiterate but like linux because once I have it working is easier for me to use for what I need.  I tried boot-repair with secure boot disabled.  There is no option for a linux boot in my acer bios.  Nothing has worked.

This is the log: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12539379/

Please help!

Ideally I would have a dual boot option but I mostly use Linux (I just use windows for iTunes) so if it ends up being a burden booting windows it is no big deal.

Also it is a new laptop so any wiping of data is also no big deal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8 removes Grub as default boot manager](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager) See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/244261/how-do-i-get-my-hp-laptop-to-boot-into-grub-from-my-new-efi-file/244343#244343