# Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.04 dual boot grub not appearing

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I am installing Ubuntu 15.04 alongside Windows 10. My PC directly boots into Windows. I am trying to fix it for weeks but could not do it. I did boot repair,  and following is the link
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12705918/ 
. My laptop is an HP (with worst UEFI) that does not allow me to change from UEFI to Legacy boot mode.

Comment: Try [EasyBCD (non-commercial)](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to edit the bootloader, but to enter legacy mode, you must disable secure boot in the BIOS.

Comment: I tried it but no help(i got this idea by googling again and again)

Comment: It looks like you originally installed Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode as you have a grub bootloader installed to the protective MBR. But fstab now shows mounting of /boot/efi, so reconfigured to boot in UEFI mode. Most with HP have to copy /EFI/ubuntu to /EFI/Boot and rename shimx64.efi to bootx64.efi and boot UEFI hard drive or fallback entry. You show multiple hard drive entries in UEFI, but they do not say UEFI, so you may need to add the UEFI hard drive entry. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 Note that your ESP is sda2.

Comment: fixed it like a boss hehe http://askubuntu.com/questions/244261/how-do-i-get-my-hp-laptop-to-boot-into-grub-from-my-new-efi-file