# GRUB doesn't show up on Windows 10 / Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot, although `update-grub` and `efibootmgr` seem to show both options

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I have an HP Zbook with Windows 10 preinstalled. I have succesfully installed Ubuntu 16.04 in it, but when booting the computer, no GRUB menu shows up and it boots directly to Windows.

I have disabled the Fast Startup option and tried everyhting I was able to make it work, but with no success. I am able to boot Ubuntu by entering the boot menu at startup. I copy here the results of `efibootmgr` and `update-grub` for info.

[image: BootOrder has ubuntu first, update-grub finds 2 Ubuntu kernels and Windows Boot Manager]

Does anyone know how can I have GRUB to select an OS to boot?

Comment: Some HP do have a way to boot: HP Check if Customized UEFI settings available like this  HP ProBook 4340
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2332681&p=13527216#post13527216
http://askubuntu.com/questions/244261/how-do-i-get-my-hp-laptop-to-boot-into-grub-from-my-new-efi-file See details on using OS Boot manager in UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 answers(solutions):

1) Try to "brute force" it with [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Go in ubuntu and run commands, and choose recommend repair. And hope it helps.

2) If it does not work, you could manually replace EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi file with grubx64.efi file (take a little tour into esp partition and look for .efi files in grub folder or something. If grubx64.efi doesn't work, try other .efi files). WARNING: backup bootmgfw.efi first, because without it you cannot boot in windows (without windows recovery usb).

Why will this work? UEFI firmware is (in your case) set to boot bootmgfw.efi file, so if you replace if with grub.efi, it will boot Grub (its a mind trick). Note: I didn't try this with Grub, but I did with rEFind. It is also possible that Grub doesn't work, so it currently over jumps grub into Windows.

3.) Try [rEFind](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#packagefile):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rodsmith/refind 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install refind
```

This may solve the problem. If not see manual install of rEFind section at link:

www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#linux

Comment: Thanks! I tried option 1 and boot-repair gave me the following link.
Any suggestions on sight of this before I proceed to try the other options?

http://paste2.org/08nYHxU8

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I tried options 1 and also manually changed it in windows using bcdedit. It didn't work. I'd like to use grub directly. What it does now is to boot using the efi menu from windows, where ubuntu appears. When using teh "ubuntu" option, it brings me grub. I will use it this way unless someone can tell me how to acess grub directly. But in any case, now my grub menu has a lot of efi entries that were not here before. Does anyone know how to get rid og¡f them and clean up my grub menu? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: "What it does now is to boot using the efi menu from windows, where ubuntu appears". Did you mean the efi menu from UEFI-BIOS? Also did you click on Recommend repair(repairs most frequent problems) when you run boot-repair?

Comment: Hi! Yes to both: it boots from UEFI_BIOS menu and I run Reccoemended repairs under boot-repair

Comment: i updated 3th solution

Answer (score 0):

You just have to modify the boot device order in the UEFI Settings. You should be able to access the UEFI Settings from the "boot menu", or restart from Windows while holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>, then navigate through the menus to get to the UEFI Settings.
From there you should be able to find the boot device list and change their order so "ubuntu" is on top of the list.