# Increase of ubuntu entries on startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I am new to Ubuntu and have just installed it on my HP envy dv6 laptop, as a dual OS alongside windows 10(I newly installed both OS's). I have 2 problems at the moment:

1. On startup, the GRUB menu does not show. Instead it will boot into
   Windows by default. If I want to launch into Ubuntu, I need to press
   <kbd>ESC</kbd> key, launch boot options and launch Ubuntu from
   there. I have already tried disabling *Fast Startup* on Windows, and
   have re-registered *GRUB* in my firmware. How do I get the *GRUB*
   menu to show?
2. The more pressing issue is that the number of Ubuntu entries that
   show on the boot manager keeps increasing with time. As of now I
   have roughly 10-15 Ubuntu entries in the boot manager (see in the
   picture bellow), and there is no difference in these unwanted Ubuntu
   options. How do I fix this issue?

---

[image: Multiple Ubuntu entries pic]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get my HP laptop to boot into grub from my new efi file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/244261/how-do-i-get-my-hp-laptop-to-boot-into-grub-from-my-new-efi-file)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your grub is configured for a "quiet" boot.

You can edit grub at /etc/default.

Run "info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'" in the terminal to get the manual on what to change and how to get your desired effect.

Don't forget to run "update-grub" after you've saved your changes.