# Installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside windows 10 but my pc only runs windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 16.04, windows-10

Every time I start the pc it only runs windows, grub doen't appear. I know it's something about UEFI mode. I changed everything but I'm still pretty lost.

Comment: Is it HP laptop? If yes, I have the solution. If it's not I may have.

Comment: Just keep pressing F9 constantly when you just power on your computer (or look for the key "change boot order" for your computer, it may be F12, F10, ... ) and choose ubuntu. If you want a definitively solution, see my answer on http://askubuntu.com/questions/244261/how-do-i-get-my-hp-laptop-to-boot-into-grub-from-my-new-efi-file/817363#817363

Answer (score 0):

depending on your system **OPEN BOOT OPTIONS** there you must see an *efi entry of ubuntu*.

Yup it's related to UEFI, I faced same problem a while ago. In UEFI, first entry of efi file is automatically booted. You must change it for `Ubuntu`, I used windows graphical tool [Easy BCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/#comparison).

It's free have a look in it, it's very handy to delete efi, change ordering, etc.
Hope it solves issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to go into your UEFI by hitting a special key usually F12 or delete right after you hit the power button. If you are having trouble finding the special key it should appear on the splash screen before you see the windows logo. Then you will enter your UEFI. There you should be able to find a boot order option. next follow your UEFI instructions for changing boot order so Ubuntu appears first. Doing this will enter the Grub bootloader instead of the windows bootloader which only cares about Windows installs.