# Trying to boot and install Ubuntu from USB but it gets stuck at HP loading screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, usb

##### My system

I recently bought a new computer (HP Pavilion TG01-2814no) that came with Windows 11 preinstalled. I want to install Ubuntu and have no intention of dual booting or continuing to use Windows 11 on this machine.

The machine has the following:
Processor: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-11400 @ 2.6GHz
RAM: 16GB DDR4 RAM 3200MHz
SSD: 1TB PCIe NVMe M.2
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060

##### What I have tried and where I am stuck

I followed [this](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview) tutorial when trying to install Ubuntu. I downloaded the Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS iso from [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop), and used Rufus 3.17 to set up the USB according to the tutorial.
When I insert the USB into my new computer, I manage to select to boot from the USB from the boot menu after pressing **esc** upon startup. I am then directed to the GNU Grub menu which looks like [this](https://i.gyazo.com/6478c243f2c405ad2c542808551efa90.png)

I have attempted both Ubuntu (with and without nomodeset) and Ubuntu (safe graphics), both getting stuck at the same place, which I will try to explain now.

Upon choosing Ubuntu or Ubuntu (safe graphics), I am directed to [this](https://i.gyazo.com/557e8e538809cb5c318e6a70be68b73d.png) loading page.

This is where I get stuck as this loading screen continues forever.

I have also tried:

- turning on/off fast boot in the Windows 11 control panel
- turning on/off safe booting in BIOS settings
- updating the BIOS for this machine according to the HP support
- setting up the USB drive using an alternative to Rufus (I used Etcher)
- I used the same USB on another older computer and successfully installed Ubuntu on there! (I forget the system details for this computer, but it is **not** HP, it has a Nvidia GeForce GTX 970 and is about 6 years old now I think)

Finally,
I am not very experienced with OSes in general and their workings but have some general understanding of computers. Thank you to anyone who reads this and any help and/or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: HP is not particularly Linux friendly. You can make it work but probably need newest version of Ubuntu - 21.10, and then upgrade to 22.04 when it is out. And may need a custom UEFI entry to make it think its booting Windows but really loads grub/shim boot file from ESP - efi system partition. HP 17-BY4063CL Laptop shows UEFI screens, needed 21.04 since new Intel chip
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2462045  Only suggested if Ubuntu only, not dual boot with Windows. https://askubuntu.com/questions/244261/how-do-i-get-my-hp-laptop-to-boot-into-grub-from-my-new-efi-file

Answer (score 1):

this is a common issue with Pavillon notebooks AFAIK and here's the procedure with which you usually solve this kind of problems.

- use either Rufus and Etcher (that's what I used back in the days when I had Windows PCs)
- disable secure boot in UEFI (and keep it disabled)
- boot Ubuntu from the USB stick
- once on GRUB, press `e` and then add `nomodeset` in front of `quiet splash` then CTRL+X (can you confirm you did this?)
- at this point, installing Ubuntu shouldn't be a problem

Once installed, enter the terminal and set GRUB to always start Ubuntu with `nomodeset`:
`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

within the file, add this row: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset" hit `CTRL+X` and save
then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot

hope this helps

Comment: The nomodeset boot parameter in effect prevents nVidia from trying to work. Newer version of Ubuntu now have a Safe Boot option which may just include nomodeset. And if you select to install the optional restricted drivers, it should install the correct nVidia driver for your nVidia. Its when nVidia driver not installed that nomodeset is required.

Comment: And if dual-booting with Windows 11 you can't disable Secure Boot.

Comment: I have tried running with nomodeset with no avail. Here are the GRUB [parameters](https://i.gyazo.com/a7fd79790f14580ed042a9a2f3b96661.png) I ran.  
I have ensured that secure boot is disabled and that I am booting from the USB stick from the boot menu. 
Despite these efforts I am still stuck at the HP loading screen.