How can I make my system automatically boot to ubuntu linux?
After installing Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop linux on my hp EliteBook Foilio 9480m (with no other OS), my system does not boot to ubuntu linux automatically. I always have to press f12 on startup to enter bios setup, and manually select "Ubuntu" from boot options. How can I make my system automatically boot to ubuntu linux once I switch it on?
I did some research, but no solution yet.
I am a beginner linux user, and I will really appreciate whatever help I can get from you ubuntu experts.

This may help https://askubuntu.com/questions/244261/how-do-i-get-my-hp-laptop-to-boot-into-grub-from-my-new-efi-file the answer from michal_za read the comments if you have problem with \

It worked! Thanks!
